How to signal an authentication realm to the browser
I observed that when using HTTP Basic/Digest authentication, browsers present a login modal and store username/password along with the realm signalled by the WWW-Authenticate header.
However, if the app rolls its own authentication (e.g. webfilter 302ing to a login.html) no realm information is being stored.
Is there a way for a login page (or the filter) to send some kind of realm information? WWW-Authenticate was my first guess, but that does not seem to work. (Probably because of the auth-scheme not makeing sense here).
Reason: I would like to help users of that server to use different usernames/password combos for different services. (I am using Tomcat 9.x on server side).

Do you want to keep basic authentication and add your programmatic authentication to it?

Basic auth doesn't encrypt anything and is highly discouraged. Why don't you use a proper authentication service like anything based on OAuth? An as for "help the users to use different usernames/passwords" - why not just have different users with different permissions or roles?
